# How to save files from two listboxes c#

Tags: c#, text, listbox, save, streamwriter

i was doing a project. In the project, I needed to add values into a listbox. When I press the add button:

```
 lbxOverhead.Items.Add(tbxAddItem.Text);
 lbxItemPrices.Items.Add(tbxAddPrice.Text);
```

I then used the following code to save the modified listbox values into a txt file:

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("List.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string item in lbxOverhead.Items)
            foreach (int item2 in lbxItemPrices.Items)
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(item);
                outputFile.WriteLine(item2);
            }
```

It comes up with a error message saying: [image: error message]

Can you please help me?

Comment: You sure you want a nested `foreach` ?

Comment: If you have 2 item in each box, in your textfile you'd have 8 lines, which I'm not sure is the result you're looking for. Is it ?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding your code breaks from `for` loop. Could you please make change to your snippet like below.

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("List.txt"))
{
   foreach (var item in lbxOverhead.Items)
   foreach (var item2 in lbxItemPrices.Items)
   {
      outputFile.WriteLine(item);
      outputFile.WriteLine(item2);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are casting a `string` to an `int` and that is failing

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("List.txt"))
{
 foreach (string item in lbxOverhead.Items)
 foreach (string item2 in lbxItemPrices.Items)
 {
   outputFile.WriteLine(item);
   outputFile.WriteLine(item2);
 }
```

When you add it to the list of items, you are adding `.Text` which is a string. You are then trying to cast it and it is failing.

Also, you may want to reconsider the structure of your code. Nested loops are hardly ever a good thing and can be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for failure:**
1.you are trying to store the returned object of `lbxItemPrices.Items` in `int` variable without any explicit casting -which is invalid as below:

```
foreach (int item2 in lbxItemPrices.Items)
```

2.it is not good practice to use 2 foreach loops here i think it will create other problems .

here i'm adding the items only when both `ItemPrice` count and `Overhead` count is same
**code is as below:**

```
    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("List.txt"))
    {
        if(lbxOverhead.Items.Count == lbxItemPrices.Items.Count)
        {
          for(int i=0;i<lbxOverhead.Items.Count;i++)       
          {         
            outputFile.WriteLine(lbxOverhead.Items[i].ToString());
            outputFile.WriteLine(lbxItemPrices.Items[i].ToString());
          }
        }
    }
```